# Laravel call to controller method from command line to run in background

Tags: php, linux, laravel

I have method in laravel controller with some logic that need to run in the background in an infinite loop. With core php with was simple as we used to set it nohup php and call the php file to run in the background. How could we do the same with laravel to run the things in background.

**Note:** I cannot use cronjob  for this as its an infinite loop which need to kept running in the background

Comment: maybe you could use a cron job which fires every minute

Comment: Clue : Laravel Command, Laravel Queue

Answer (score 0):

Kinda hard to imagine what task you want to accomplish, but you could create laravel command, which could call controller method directly.

[How to call controller method from within command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54028794/11653338)

> Check comment under the answer to resolve controller correctly.

Next, you should run command by the supervisor.

[Supervisor tutorial](https://learn2torials.com/a/how-to-setup-laravel-supervisor)

Comment: But man, if you really need to have some background process, the controller is the worst place to contain it's logic.

Comment: @nojitesi I understand that controller is the worst place. I have separated the logic into trait and service module

Comment: @NizamTechs so the problem is solved, could close the thread?

Answer (score 0):

you can use define cronjob on your linux machine or use laravel schedule library . look at the following link :

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/scheduling

Comment: Cron jon or scheduler cannot used as its a continues job that need to be running in backgroound